# Show that this system has a limit cycle in the first quadrant.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

The full question reads as follows:

Consider the predator-prey model

$$\dot{x} = x \left(6-x-\frac{3y}{1+x} \right), \dot{y} = y(x-2)$$

Assume that all positive solutions are bounded. (a) Find all critical points and determine their local stability. (b) Show that this system has a limit cycle in the first quadrant.

I have finished part (a) and found that $(0,0)$ is a saddle, $(6,0)$ is a saddle, and $(2,4)$ is an unstable focus. I have attempted to do part (b) using some phase plane analysis, but I am looking for a more definite way to prove this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It appears to me that the "focus"--if it is a focus (I say this because I haven't checked, I'm going with what you wrote)--is at $(2, 4)$, not $(2, 3)$.  This is why I'm not sure what type of critical point this is, since I'm not sure we got the coordinates right!

Comment: Just edited, but my question still stands. Thanks Robert!

Comment: Which tools do you know to prove the existence of a cycle?

Comment: By the way: (2,4) a stable focus, are you sure about this?

Comment: According to Mathematica, the eigenvalues at $(2,4)$ are $\frac{1}{3}(1\pm i\sqrt{71})$, so $(2,4)$ is an unstable focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assume that all solutions starting in $\mathbb{R}^2_{+} := \{\, (x, y) : x \ge 0,\ y \ge 0 \,\}$ are bounded for $t > 0$.**  It follows then that the domain of any such solution contains $[0, \infty)$, and that the $\omega$-limit set is compact and nonempty.

Let $L$ stand for the $\omega$-limit set of some point, $(x_0, y_0)$, sufficiently close to the **unstable** focus $(2,4)$. By the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem, $L$ is either a limit cycle, or a heteroclinic cycle, (EDIT: or a homoclinic loop), or an equilibrium.

$L$ cannot be an equilibrium.  Indeed, there are three possibilities: either $L = \{(0, 0)\}$, or $L = \{(6,0)\}$, or else $L = \{(2, 4)\}$.  In the first two cases, the equilibria are saddles, so $(x_0, y_0)$ must belong to the stable manifold, which means either $\{\, (0, y) : y > 0 \,\}$ or $\{\, (x, 0) : x \in (0, 6) \cup (6, \infty) \,\}$.  In the third case, the only point whose $\omega$-limit set is $\{(2,4)\}$ is $(2,4)$ itself.

We proceed now to excluding the case of heteroclinic cycle (EDIT: or homoclinic loop).  But the only possible connection is from $(0, 0)$ to $(6,0)$, so there are no heteroclinic cycles.

Consequently, $L$ is a limit cycle surrounding $(2,4)$.

Below is a sketch of the phase portrait:

[image]

Incidentally, it is not so easy to show that all solutions starting in $\mathbb{R}^2_{+}$ are bounded for positive times.  The OP gave that as an assumption, but it should follow somehow from the form of the system.