# Use Poincaré-Bendixson to show that a limit cycle exists in the first quadrant.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

The entire problem reads:

Consider the predator-prey model $\dot x = \left( 4-x-\frac{2y}{1+x} \right)$, $\dot y = y(x-1)$. Assume that all positive solutions are bounded. (a) Find all critical points and determine their local stability. (b) Show that this system has a limit cycle in the first quadrant.

I have already found all of the equilibrium points, the important of which is an unstable focus at $(1,3)$. I attempted to show part (b) using some phase plane analysis, but I have hit a wall and I'm not sure where to go next. I started by plotting the parabola $y = \frac{(4-x)(1+x)}{2}$ because that's where $\dot x = 0$, but it didn't help me gain much. Any and all advice on how to do the rest of part (b) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The system has some similarities to that posed by you 6 days ago [Show that this system has a limit cycle in the first quadrant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860914/show-that-this-system-has-a-limit-cycle-in-the-first-quadrant/2861749#2861749). Did you see my answer there? Do you understand it? If not, why didn't you ask me for clarification? Or show that it is wrong?

Comment: I am trying to solve this one in a different way (without the use of software). I was curious to see if there would be any input.

Comment: In [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860914/show-that-this-system-has-a-limit-cycle-in-the-first-quadrant/2861749#2861749) the sketch was only **for illustrative purposes**, and had very little to do with the reasoning. I repeat: do you understand **my reasoning** there?

Comment: Are you sure that you have $\dot{x}=\left(4-x-\frac{2y}{1+x}\right)$? Not $\dot{x}=x\left(4-x-\frac{2y}{1+x}\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me repeat, with suitable modifications, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860914/show-that-this-system-has-a-limit-cycle-in-the-first-quadrant/2861749#2861749) to the OP's earlier question.

Assume that **all solutions starting in $\mathbb{R}^2_{+} := \{\, (x, y) : x \ge 0,\ y \ge 0 \,\}$ are bounded for $t > 0$** (this would require a separate proof). It follows then that for any such solution, its domain contains $[0,\infty)$ and its $\omega$-limit set is compact and nonempty.

Let $L$ stand for the $ω$-limit set of some point, $(x_0,y_0)$, sufficiently close to the unstable focus $(1,3)$. By the [Poincaré–Bendixson theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Bendixson_theorem), as there are finitely many equilibria, $L$ is either a limit cycle, or a [heteroclinic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroclinic_cycle), (EDIT: or a [homoclinic loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoclinic_orbit)), or an equilibrium.

There are two equilibria, $(4,0)$ and $(1,3)$. The first of them is an unstable focus, so it cannot belong to any heteroclinic cycle (because a heteroclinic cycle (EDIT: or a homoclinic loop) must contain an equilibrium that is an $\omega$-limit point for some *other* point).  Consequently, there are no heteroclinic cycles (EDIT: or homoclinic loops) at all.

So, $L$ is either a periodic orbit, or equals $\{(4,0)\}$.  We proceed now to excluding the latter.  The linearization of the vector field at $(4,0)$ has matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -\frac25
\\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
There are two real eigenvalues, $-1$ and $3$, of opposite signs, so $(4,0)$ is a hyperbolic saddle.  Its stable manifold is tangent to an eigenvector corresponding to $-1$, that is, to $(1,0)$.  I claim that the stable manifold 
is the $x$-axis, minus $(4,0)$.  Indeed, on the $x$-axis we have $\dot{x} = 4 - x$, $\dot{y} \equiv 0$, so for any $(x_1,0)$ we have $\omega((x_1,0)) = \{(4,0)\}$.  Now, for a hyperbolic saddle its stable manifold is just the set of those points whose (unique) $\omega$-limit point is the saddle.  Hence, if $L = \{(4,0)\}$ then the positive semitrajectory of $(x_0, y_0)$ must belong to the $x$-axis, which contradicts the uniqueness of the initial value problem (notice that $y_0 > 0$).

We have thus shown that $L$ is a periodic orbit.

Comment: Just a minor addition: due to Poincaré–Bendixson theorem, a homoclinic loop can also be a limit set. This option is however trivially excluded here.

Comment: @Evgeny Thank you. Just corrected.

Comment: In the OP's question, as well in my solution, it is *assumed* that all positive solutions are bounded. To me, proving that would be the **real** problem!

Comment: @Evgeny Now, I have serious doubts if that assumption can be satisfied at all! At $(0,y)$ with $y>2$ the $x$-coordinate of the field is negative. Perhaps the OP forgot to put $x$ before the parentheses in the formula for $\dot{x}$?

Comment: You are right about observation that positive quadrant is not invariant in this system. I'd agree that it is very likely that there is a typo in equations. The system with additional $x$ as multiplier also wouldn't have all the nasty stuff near the $x=-1$. At best the original system might have a limit cycle in the upper half-plane, but I really don't like the singularity at $x = -1$.

Comment: How to justify that the stablemanifold of an unstable focus is just the singleton consisting of the unstable focus?

Comment: A hint: use the time reversal. Then an unstable focus becomes an asymptotically stable equilibrium. Now, the asymptotic stability (indeed, the Lyapunov stability alone) is incompatible with the existence of a point (other than the equilibrium) repelled from the equilibrium.